# Input type="date" how to format?

Tags: php, angular-ngmodel

I'm using a input `type="date"` but it always save to the database like this format.

> Tue Sep 25 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)

```
 <form action="insertPTO.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal alert 
alert-warning"  name="reqTimeOff"   >
  <h3>Request Form</h3>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="from">From * :</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="fromDate" | date:"MM/dd/yyyy"  autofocus required />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <p class="text-danger" ng-show="reqTimeOff.fromDate.$invalid && reqTimeOff.fromDate.$dirty">Please select a Date!</p>
  </div>
```

How do I set the format only like this format `mm/dd/yyyy`?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: AFAIK there is no provision for formatting the date input however you could use `datetime-local` and remove the time?

Answer (score 0):

You can't give format to this native HTML input.

Try to use [DateTimePicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't - if you need to do any calculations in your database you will need it to be in a format that the database understands.

It sounds like what you actually want is for the date to *display* in a certain format in which case you can do this with PHP or a JavaScript library such as [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

In PHP there's the function [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).
In your case you would do

```
$unformatted = "Tue Sep 25 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0800";
$formatted = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($unformatted));
```

Note: Most databases need you to format dates like this:

```
Y-m-d         //for date
Y-m-d H:i:s   //for datetime
```

Comment: @JohnHenrixGloria It does not work with the additional information about your time zone, which is why I did not include it. If you remove `(Philippine Standard Time)` from your string, it will work.

Comment: i tried last night the code without Philippines Standard Time, and it works. now my problem is how to remove that PST in my input type="date"

Comment: If you can be sure it will ALWAYS say `(Philippine Standard Time)` you can use str_replace() like this: `$unformatted = str_replace("(Philippine Standard Time)", "", $unformatted);`